# Pro*C char copying (ORACLE DB)

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I want to copy a char onto a CHAR(18 BYTE) from my ORACLE Database:

```
myfunction(char *idnr)
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;     
    char* idn;
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    strcpy(idn,idnr);
...}
```

but it seems it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* idn;
```

First of all you need to allocate memory for it or Use array instead

```
 char idn[strlen(idnr) + 1];
```